# Modification to simple jQuery script to randomize text with timer

Tags: jquery, random, setinterval

I am using a jQuery script that shows a random slogan from an array on page load.
However I want this slogan to be changed every 6 sec. How can I do this?

[This is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EA4eh/) and here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    phrases = [
        "a creative Chicago design shop",
        "design is simple",
        "we build fine, fine things",
        "we love creating"
    ];

    var phrase = phrases[Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length)]
    $('#site').text(phrase);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/vzwick/v3xWb/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    changePhrase();
    var rotate = setInterval(changePhrase, 6000);
});

function changePhrase() {
    phrases = [
        "a creative Chicago design shop",
        "design is simple",
        "we build fine, fine things",
        "we love creating"
    ];

    currentPhrase = $('#site').text();
    if (phrases.indexOf(currentPhrase)) phrases.splice(phrases.indexOf(currentPhrase), 1); // remove current phrase from array to prevent repetitions

    var phrase = phrases[Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length)]
    $('#site').text(phrase);
}
```

**Update:** Thrown in a two-liner that prevents repetition of the same phrase two times in a row for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

this will change phrases for an infinite number of time , but you have to use the Jquery Timers Plugin .

```
$(document).everyTime(1000, function(i) {
  var phrase = phrases[Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length)]
$('#site').text(phrase);
}, 0);
```

Comment: Using an additional plugin for a task that essentially boils down to a `setInterval()` is overkill, imo.

Comment: the plugin is useful  , it saves you the trouble to manage the id's when you wanna stop the loop of the interval set , it can also be set to a defined number of time to repeat if the 3rd argument in everytime( ) is set to >0  .
besides i think according to the title of the question he's asking of a way to do it in Jquery .

Comment: I should've said "it's overkill **in this case**". Didn't mean to offend you.

Comment: no offense taken dude :)  all that matters is providing the question with a diversity of useful answers .. 
thanks for commenting.